# Failed to load resource: Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have created a project from Angular CLI and started using "ng serve" command to run the app. It shows "web pack: compiled successfully" but not working in web browser.

Console errors found like 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' for all the files like "main.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js and styles... etc.

[image]

I understand due to missing the files on load throwing error. I do not understand why is giving error even though compiled successfully.

**Working on Node v10.13.0**

Any expert inputs please?

Comment: Show your index.html file

Comment: Try "npm install" first before "ng serve".

Comment: Please add more details, add `index.html`, you ran `npm install` or not?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the node_modules or comment the node_modules folder and do

```
npm install
```

Looks like your node_modules are not compatible with your Angular 5 version.

Then run ,

```
ng serve -o

-o to open the application in browser automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be an issue with caching. Run:

```
npm cache clean or npm cache verify.
```

That has solved it for me.